# Catch Upload Event in BHO

Tags: object, browser, helper

I am new to BHO but I've a requirement where I've catch before upload and upload event in IE like when attaching file to gamil/yahoo/others or uploading file to Dropbox/Google Drive etc.

Do I've to IWebBrwoser2 events and OnDocumentComplete? I don't actually get it and net search helped me nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to figure out the same thing but no luck.

I guess we need to work with ActiveX to handle upload event.
Use Ajax call to track down the upload success event and fire ActiveX method for your relevant code.